Nav Guards cause Hydration Mismatch
As recommended in, I have set up nav guards for my nuxt app in:
/src
  /middleware
    /navGuard.global.ts

This runs on every route change.  Here I check for a logged in user in my data store, attempt login, and redirect if neccessary
export default async (to:Route, from:Route) => {

  const appStore = useAppStore()
  const auth = useAuthStore()
  appStore.page_loading = true;

  if (!import.meta.client) return;

  if (to.name === 'auth' && !auth.doAuthRedirect) {
    console.log('Navigating to auth')
    sessionStorage.setItem('lastNavigation', '/auth')  
  }

  if (to.name !== 'auth' && !auth.userId) {
    console.log('Looking for user auth in storage')
    await auth.setUser()
    if (!auth.userId) {
      console.log('User not found redirect to auth')
      sessionStorage.setItem('lastNavigation', to.path)
      auth.doAuthRedirect = true;
      return navigateTo('auth');
    }
  }
  console.log('Navigating to:', to.path)
  auth.doAuthRedirect = false;
  return
  
};

The problem here is that the reliance on the authStore and loading user sessions from localStorage means that the serverside and the client side will always mismatch (obviously there will never be a localStorage cred found on the serverside).
What is the theory here?  I'm sure I must be doing it fundamentally wrong.
Before someone says it - changing the whole app to CSR is not a solution.  The whole point of NUXT is to get as much SSR as possible.

If your webapp is behind an auth, why do you need SSR?

Things that depend on client side localStorage are a no no. Wrap these behind a ClientOnly tag, alternatively use cookies, there is no in between.

@kissu - Lots of stuff depends on auth, that is on public pages as well.  For instance, the avatar on the app bar that appears one way if a a user is logged in and another if they are not.

@Mark - Can you elaborate on no, no.  Are advocating never use localStorage, never use storage on SSR  pages.  Make liberal use of <ClientOnly> tags on components that do use localStoage?

Overall, if you have a difference between the markup on the client and on the server (no-auth VS auth content), you need to opt-out from SSR with some conditional client-only render yes.

I meant SSR things that depend on client side localStorage are a no no.

Yes, SSR is server-side. localStorage is client-side only. Hence both are exclusive. You need to use some isomorphic approach for SSR with things like cookies because those are available on both server and client side. Hence why, either use client-side approach: localStorage + client-only or go general with cookies + universal mode. At the same time, if it's private info there is no need to have it generated on the server and shipped for SEO purposes. You can still SSR pages but should opt-out of it for auth'ed ones. Check: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering#hybrid-rendering
